# maximizing binary cross_entropy in a keras model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I don't know hot to create a model that is maximizing binary cross_entropy loss in a keras model.

research:

1.https://intellipaat.com/community/17707/how-to-maximize-loss-function-in-keras
that said:

Simply multiply the loss by -1 to maximize the loss function while trying to minimize it:

new_loss = -loss

but using:

```
model.compile(loss=-1 * 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer=adam_optimizer())
```

resulted in this error:

```
ValueError: The model cannot be compiled because it has no loss to optimize.
```

2. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/303229/why-does-keras-binary-crossentropy-loss-function-return-wrong-values

gave me a custom function that approximates the keras binary_crossentropy loss:

```
import keras.backend as K
def binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred):
    result = []
    for i in range(len(y_pred)):
        y_pred[i] = [max(min(x, 1 - K.epsilon()), K.epsilon()) for x in y_pred[i]]
        result.append(-np.mean([y_true[i][j] * math.log(y_pred[i][j]) + (1 - y_true[i][j]) * math.log(1 - y_pred[i][j]) for j in range(len(y_pred[i]))]))
    return np.mean(result)
```

but I can not use it since it results in the error:

```
len is not well defined for symbolic Tensors. (43_54/Sigmoid:0) Please call `x.shape` rather than `len(x)` for shape information.
```

when I replace `len` with `.shape[0]`

I get the another error:

```
__index__ returned non-int (type NoneType)
```

I tinkered with the syntax in several more ways but nothing seems to work.
any ideas?

python 3.6

tensorflow 1.15

keras 2.3.1

Comment: try to use model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=-1
*tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to define a new loss, based on the keras implementation:

```
def neg_binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred):
    return -1.0 * keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)
```

And then use it in `model.compile`:

```
model.compile(loss=neg_binary_crossentropy, optimizer="adam")
```